# Maven App Engine DevServer: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

I'm trying to run `mvn appengine:run` goal from [Maven App Engine Plugin Google Cloud SDK based](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-maven). When the App Engine Server (DevServer) starts, I notice the error:

```
ebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context c.g.a.t.d.j.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@4b14c583{/,file:///path/to/my/project/target/Project-1.0-SNAPSHOT/,null}
```

The error is caused by: `[INFO] GCLOUD: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file`.

What is the cause of `java.util.zip.ZipException` at this context?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely one or more jar files may be corrupt. Try to remove the corrupted jars and run the command again. If needed remove all the content from the Maven local repository:

```
 C:\Users\username\.m2\repository
```

After that (if you're using eclipse) you can "Force Update" right clicking your project selecting Maven -> Update Project.